# XAML button template - making gloss effect automatically scale with button height

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, expression-blend

I am trying to create a button template in Expression Studio for silverlight. The Button is a basic rectangle with another rectangle inside it with a low opacity to represent "gloss" on the button. The button works perfect, except when the height is altered, i need the height of the "gloss" rectangle to also increment automatically to maintain its normal aspect ratio. Is there anyway of doing this? Can I set the height to be like "50%" of the other one?

Thanks,

Below is my template code:

```
<Style x:Key="CloseButtonBlack" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid x:Name="grid">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.2"/>
                                        <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0" To="Pressed"/>
                                    </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.495" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="grid" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF333333" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="#FF434343" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Button" d:IsOptimized="True"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Button" Fill="Black" Stroke="#FF2D2D2D"/>
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" Content="X"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="Gloss" Fill="White" Height="12" Margin="1, 1, 1, 0" Stroke="#FF2D2D2D" VerticalAlignment="Top" Opacity="0.25"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/> 
        <RowDefinition/> 
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

  <Rectangle x:Name="Button" Grid.RowSpan="2" .../>

  <ContentPresenter Grid.RowSpan="2" .../>

  <Rectangle x:Name="Gloss" Grid.Row="1" .../>
  <!-- Remove the Height="12" from this element -->
</Grid>
```

This will make a 2-row grid where each row is 50% the total height, and place the "Gloss" rectangle in the second row, occupying the lower half of the grid, while stretching the "Button" rectangle to the entire height.

Comment: @user587950 Don't forget to mark my answer as accepted (green checkmark) if it was useful for you =)